# MySQL Workbench, dropping foreign keys

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

(Caveat: I am not a MySQL pro, I use Workbench in lieu of knowing commands, so my question is likely an easy one)

I'm trying to rename a primary key (userID) in a table (user), but MySQL won't let me (errno 150). After some digging, it appears that I must first drop foreign keys before renaming my primary key.

So, in Workbench, I go to the next table (question) and choose alter table, then go the the Foreign Keys tab. I select the only foreign key in the left window (fk_Question_user), uncheck the only checkbox in the middle window (userID), then hit Apply. Workbench gives error 1050 "table 'question' already exists" (of course it already exists, I'm trying to edit it). Anyway, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the SQL Queries preferences page you can enable the data change wizard which shows you what will be sent to the server for review (Confirm Data Changes).

[image]

With that enable you should see what MySQL Workbench sends to the server. It should not do a CREATE TABLE however.

Comment: thanks for that insight. Confirm Data Changes is already enabled. After I posted I tried multiple alternate methods of dropping the foreign key, all seemed to fail. I logged in this morning, and foreign key is no longer there! (argh). So at some point MySQL accepted the change, I just don't know when. I have to drop a few more foreign keys today, so I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Rather than unchecking the field in the center pane of the foreign keys tab, the correct way to do this is to select the foreign key in the left-hand pane then select delete from its contextual menu and apply.